# getting Null on handler intermittently when trying to retrieve last handler in Netty

Tags: netty

I have a netty client that connect to remote server for a request-response. I want to block till the remote connection is successful and parse the response. My handler is similar to [Netty factorial example](https://github.com/mbakkar/netty-1/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/factorial/FactorialClientHandler.java) in retrieving the results.

Here is what I have

```
Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(addr).sync().channel();
ChannelFuture f = ch.writeAndFlush(obj);
//blocking operation
ch.closeFuture().sync();
MyHandler handler = (MyHandler) f.channel().pipeline().last(); //this handler is null
String responseString = handler.responseString;
f.channel().close();
```

Handler code

```
MyHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

     public String result = null;
       @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
            result = parse(msg);
         }
        // The following line automatically closes the channel: 

ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
```

why is the handler null intermittently and what is the right way to do it? (I commented on the line where NPE is thrown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things you need to be aware of, is that when the Netty channel is in the progress of being closed, the last step is that it removes all handlers, this step is required so all cleanup routines get run inside those handlers.

This means, that after the channel is closed, you cannot access any of the handlers in the pipeline.

Inside your code, you are waiting for the event that a channel has fully closed, this means that the code afterwards has an "happens after" relation to the channel close event.

One solution for this is making a custom promise object, and passing this to the handler, who then fills it with a response:

```java
// Somewhere inside the application:
public static final AttributeKey<Promise<String>> RESPONSE = new AttributeKey("RESPONSE");

ChannelFuture chf = bootstrap.connect(addr);
Promise<String> p = chf.channel().eventLoop().newPromise();
chf.channel().attr(RESPONSE).set(p);
//blocking operation
Channel ch = chf.sync().channel();
ChannelFuture f = ch.writeAndFlush(obj);
//blocking operation
String responseString = p.get();
f.channel().close();

....

// Inside you handler

MyHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
            ctx.channel().attr(RESPONSE).get().setSuccess(parse(msg));
        }
        // The following line automatically closes the channel: 
        ctx.channel()
            .writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
            .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

This solution works, because even though the channel and its attributes gets cleaned on choose, we still have a reference to the promise that contains the final result

Comment: Will try this out..curious why handler is intermittently null. Any reasoning for that?

Comment: because you block on the "closeFuture"  which will be notified once the Channel was closed and so the pipeline was teared down.

Comment: @brainstorm The reason for "nulling it" is to prevent exposing objects in an "undefined" state, because the object has already completed its cleanup routines during shutdown

Comment: Note it is not null consistently but sometimes I get non-null references too.

Comment: While I previously said that the pipeline is destroyed before the close, it actually happens after the close event, but on the netty threads, this creates a race condition in your original code where the pipeline may or may not be empty when checking the handlers. That is why its commonly said to be cleared on close